What is the name of a movie containing a futuristic plane using solid state fuel?
I vaguely remember a film probably  from 90s-2000s surrounding a futuristic jet plane utilizing solid state fuel.
I specifically remember a scene depicting the plane converting the fuel mid-flight and a big explosion occurs at the end of the movie.
Dose this ring a bell to anyone or my memory is failing me?

What elements of scifi or fantasy were there in this movie?

@AndresF. real planes don't use solid fuel

Was it chemical fuel, or nuclear fuel?

@OrganicMarble Technically the Jato units used by planes such as Fat Albert would contradict your premise /s  (and that's not counting early aviation solid fuel rocket experiments)

@PeterM see how far those get ya.

"a big explosion occurs at the end of the movie": well that really narrows it down...

"solid state fuel" is a non-sensical term. But I guess it's something Hollywood might cook up to sound futuristic :)

@jwenting Hardly non-sensical, just impractical for airplanes using current or foreseeable technology. Steam ships and locomotives often used solid fuel (coal). Many rockets still do. (OK, technically, most solid rockets use solid propellant containing a mix of fuel and oxidizer, not just fuel. But even if you insist on that distinction, hybrid rockets with solid fuel and liquid oxidizer do exist, just not currently in commercial or military use AFAIK.)

@IlmariKaronen no, solid STATE fuel is a meaningless concept. Solid fuel of course isn't, and has been (as experiments) used in aircraft as far back as the 1940s (the Germans among others experimented with powering an engine with coal dust back then). Solid state refers to electronics design only.

@jwenting, Wait! My neighbor up the street claims to be a solid-state physicist. But, he doesn't design electronics. His research is all about bleeding edge, high-tech metal alloys. Is he trying to tell me that he is electronic—that he is, in fact, an android?

@SolomonSlow that's how they reveal their true nature! Yes, those alloys mainly have applications in electronics, NOT in fuel :)

Actually, my neighbor's research is funded by people who want to build stronger, lighter hulls for submarines.

@OrganicMarble seems pretty tenuous to me (especially since (some) real planes did experiment with solid fuel), but I suppose we can give it a pass.

"Solid state" just refers literally to things that involve solid materials. It is used for solid semiconductors as opposed to electron or gas discharge tubes, but it is also used in a wide range of materials science and other applications. Fuels are an unlikely case though. I suppose a solid-core nuclear ramjet would be a system that uses a solid state fuel...

(I would not consider "solid fuel" to be "solid state fuel", as it is generally converted to a gas in the process of combustion.)

Is it Stealth (2005)?. It involves a jet with a unique fuel system and in one scene an explosion occurs in mid-air.

"Fuel, catalyzed methane. Exoskeleton, metal-ceramic
composite. Aeroelastic wings. Pulse detonation engine with twin hybrid scramjet turbos.".




